# Get microseconds from postgres timestampz with sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using nodejs >=v15 with sequelize ORM >=v6 to save and retrieve timestamp(z) into a postgresql databases. However sequelize makes trouble keeping the microsecond resolution.

I achieved preserving the microseconds when storing into the database by using `type: DataTypes.STRING(32)` for the column, while in the actual database i.e. DDL it's defined as `timestamptz` and using ISO string representation.

However I can not get it work when retrieving i.e. reading this values, since for some reason, the values are already javascript `Date`s, which AFAIK only have millisecond resolution. Any suggestions?